# Is This Idea for Loading Online Content in Bulk Feasible?

Tags: caching, browser, threadpool

I devised an idea a long time ago and never got around to implementing it, and I would like to know whether it is practical in that it would work to significantly decrease loading times for modern browsers. It relies on the fact that related tasks are often done more quickly when they are done together in bulk, and that the browser could be downloading content on different pages using a statistical model instead of being idle while the user is browsing. I've pasted below an excerpt from what I originally wrote, which describes the idea.

---

### **Description.**

> When people visit websites, I
>   conjecture that that a probability
>   density function P(q, t), where q is a
>   real-valued integer representing the
>   ID of a website and t is another
>   real-valued, non-negative integer
>   representing the time of the day, can
>   predict the sequence of webpages
>   visited by the typical human
>   accurately enough to warrant
>   requesting and loading the HTML
>   documents the user is going to read in
>   advance. For a given website, have the
>   document which appears to be the "main
>   page" of the website through which
>   users access the other sections be
>   represented by the root of a tree
>   structure. The probability that the
>   user will visit the root node of the
>   tree can be represented in two ways.
>   If the user wishes to allow a process
>   to automatically execute upon the
>   initialization of the operating system
>   to pre-fetch webpages from websites
>   (using a process elaborated later)
>   which the user frequently accesses
>   upon opening the web browser, the
>   probability function which determines
>   whether a given website will have its
>   webpages pre-fetched can be determined
>   using a self-adapting heuristic model
>   based on the user's history (or by
>   manual input). Otherwise, if no such
>   process is desired by the user, the
>   value of P for the root node is
>   irrelevant, since the pre-fetching
>   process is only used after the user
>   visits the main page of the website.
>
> Children in the tree described earlier
>   are each associated with an individual
>   probability function P(q, t) (this
>   function can be a lookup table which
>   stores time-webpage pairs). Thus, the
>   sequences of webpages the user visits
>   over time are logged using this tree
>   structure. For instance, at 7:00 AM,
>   there may be a 71/80 chance that I
>   visit the "WTF" section on Reddit
>   after loading the main page of that
>   site. Based on the values of the
>   p> robability function P for each node
>   in the tree, chains of webpages
>   extending a certain depth from the
>   root node where the net probability
>   that each sequence is followed, P_c,
>   is past a certain threshold, P_min,
>   are requested upon the user visiting
>   the main page of the site. If the
>   downloading of one webpage finishes
>   before before another is processed, a
>   thread pool is used so that another
>   core is assigned the task of parsing
>   the next webpage in the queue of
>   webpages to be parsed. Hopefully, in
>   this manner, a large portion of those
>   webpages the user clicks may be
>   displayed much more quickly than they
>   would be otherwise.

---

I left out many details and optimizations since I just wanted this to be a brief description of what I was thinking about. Thank you very much for taking the time to read this post; feel free to ask any further questions if you have them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interesting idea -- and there have been some implementations for pre-fetching in browsers though without the brains you propose -- which could help alot. I think there are some flaws with this plan:

a) web page browsing, in most cases, is fast enough for most purposes.
b) bandwidth is becoming metered -- if I'm just glancing at the home page, do I as a user want to pay to serve the other pages. Moreover, in the cases where this sort of thing could be useful (eg--slow 3g connection), bandwidth tends to be more tightly metered. And perhaps not so good at concurrency (eg -- CDMA 3g connections).
c) from a server operator's point of view, I'd rather just serve requested pages in most cases. Rendering pages that don't ever get seen costs me cycles and bandwidth. If you are like alot of folks and on some cloud computing platform, you are paying by the cycle and the byte.
d) would require re-building lots of analytics systems, many of which still operate on the theory of request == impression

Or, the short summary is that there really isn't a need to pre-sage what people would view in order to speed serving and rendering pages. Now, places where something like this could be really useful would be in the "hey, if you liked X you probably liked Y" and then popping links and such to said content (or products) to folks.

Comment: Those are some good points that I suppose makes this idea impractical. One thing that's worth noting is that when there is a high probability (P_min is greater than, say, 95%) that a user will view a certain group of webpages, it saves the server a lot of trouble when it can hand them to the client all at once, which could translate into reduced power and costs. Of course I don't know for how many cases this is bound to happen.

Comment: I'm actually doing the web recommendations thing ("if you like this page, you might like this too..."). But even in that case, it seems far too wasteful to preload all the content before the user has clicked any links. I provide 10 recommendations, but only one will be clicked, and unless my rankings are amazing, it might not be the top link all that often.

Answer (score 1):

Windows does the same thing with disk access - it "knows" that you are likely to start let's say Firefox at a certain time and preloads it.

> SuperFetch also keeps track of what times of day those applications are used, which allows it to intelligently pre-load information that is expected to be used in the near future.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_I/O_technologies#SuperFetch

Comment: Yeah, that explains the 25% of my 8 Gb of RAM that's consumed when I boot up Windows as opposed to the 6% that's used when I use a GNU/Linux distro.

Comment: void-pointer: Would you rather that RAM not be used? If it's needed, it'll be freed, and I have no qualms with my OS using my RAM to make my computing experience faster -- why leave it unused when it could be doing something?

Comment: void-pointer, do you disable all disk caches on Linux, to keep as much free memory as possible? :) On my 8 GB machine, at this moment 5.6 GB are used for disk-cache.

Comment: My statement was just an observation; I didn't characterize RAM usage as something bad.

Answer (score 0):

Pointing out existing tech that does similar thing:

- RSS readers load feeds in background, with assumption that user will want to read them sooner or later. There's no probability function that selects feeds for download though, user explicitly selects them
- Browser start page and pinned tabs: these load as you start your browser, again user gets to select which websites are worth having around all the time

Your proposal boils down to predicting where user is most likely to click next given current website and current time of day. I can think of few other factors that play role here:

- what other websites are open in tabs ("user opened song in youtube, preload lyrics and guitar chords!")
- what other applications are running ("user is looking at invoice in e-mail reader, preload internet bank")
- which person is using the computer--use webcam to recognize faces, know which sites each one frequents